# Under what circumstances we need to use gson to deserialize in realm?

Tags: android, realm

I am exploring Realm for Android.  Do we need to use gson to deserialize to objects when we could use realm query to update?

And under what condition we need to use gson to deserialize?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSON serialization/deserialization integration exist purely for the purposes of working with JSON. For example it's handy to have such integration in combination with Retrofit library (see http://square.github.io/retrofit/) which allows you to directly parse REST API responses into your Realm objects.

For more details see the official documentation

- https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#retrofit
- https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#gson